# RegEx to do a reverse search?

Tags: regex

given a string = /Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=

I am thinking of extracting 'AllItems'

my think is use RegEx to find '.aspx', then search back till the first '/'

Can someone please give me some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're about to select:

```
 //  \/(.*)?\.aspx

 (.*?\/){0,}(.*)?\.aspx
```

$2 is FILE name.

Note: first regex matches from first to end that is not requested in topic and second regex matches last one, first in reverse order.

Comment: soory, there is something else after the aspx

Comment: Do you mean some '/' may be after '.aspx' in GET variable values?

Comment: Given Regex returns 2 matched, the second matched is 'file' in 'Http://domain.com/folder/file.aspx?var=val'

Comment: @ryan is there any problems?